# @media only screen and (max-width: --px) not working?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I want to give style to my web page when it is open on the device whose width is less than 620px but media query for 'width' is not working it is working for "max-height" but not for "width". 
media query for width is not displaying in dev tools though it is showing in dev's source code.

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 620px) {
div.enterdetails
{
    top:32% !important;
}
div.headline{
    top:19% !important;
}
.select-btn{
    width:129px !important;
}   }
```

Here is the snippet,

```css
.headline {
   position: relative;
    top: 0px;
 left:20%;
    width: 61%;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: black;
    font-size: 32px;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    text-align:center;
  text-align-last:center;
}
.enterdetails {
    position: relative;
    top:4%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 113px;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
}
 .slctstyle
{
 position: relative;
    top: 35%;
    width: 91%;
    height: 96%;
    left: 7%;
    color: white;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
 
 }
  
.select-btn{
 height: 32px;
    width: 126px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 620px) {
div.enterdetails
{
    top:32% !important;
}
div.headline{
    top:19% !important;
}
.select-btn{
    width:129px !important;
}   }
```

```html
  
  <div class="headline">Hi, lets select data!</div>
  <div class="enterdetails">
    <div class="slctstyle">
  <select class="select-btn">
  <option>A</option>
  <option>B</option>
  </select>
  
  <select class="select-btn">
  <option>A</option>
  <option>B</option>
  </select>
  
  <select class="select-btn">
  <option>A</option>
  <option>B</option>
  </select>
  
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We need more information. What's the CSS that's not in the `media` query? Do you have HTML you can post? As your question stands, it's far to broad to even begin to help - as the media query looks correct. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: In short, imagine that you had to debug a problem with only what you've given us. Not fun, right?

Comment: Thanks for pointing lack of info in my question. Now i have updated my question. You may take a look

Comment: Note the selector: `.select-button` and the actual class `class="select-btn"`

Comment: Thanks for demonstrating but media query is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The media query is working just fine. You can check it as the `width` of `.select-btn` changes from `126px` to `129px`. Since the variation is small it may not be very clear but you can verify it by `inspecting` your page.
However, the `top` property does not cause any change on the page.
But this is not because of media queries. If you use the unit in `top` as `px` instead of `%`, you will be able to see the changes when resizing. The reason that it is happening is because of positioning of the `div`. When you give `10%`, it means 10% of the height of containing block, which in this case is `body`. So you could not see the changes using `%`'s. If you give `height: 100vh` and then apply `top:10%` it should work.
You can refer [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/top)

Answer (score 1):

try changing '.select-btn' inside the @media only screen to '200px' or maybe add a 'background-color:red', you will see the different when the screen is 620px or less.

I think the @media only screen is working but the 'top' property isn't working.

Comment: I had created a fiddle with the background changing to red before I saw your answer, so rather than create an answer - here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L2d9sjvb/

Answer (score -1):

You have to add meta viewport tag in the head of your html.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

The initial-scale property controls the zoom level when the page is first loaded. If this tag not exist, when resize is changing the scale but not doing a adaptative resizing.